# Checking account registration details

Tags: code-rally

Within the InfoQ or IBM CodeRally pages, is there a way to check / reconfirm the account details entered during registration process? Having used Google OAUTH, can one also provide twitter OAUTH details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to confirm which social media account is linked to a username is to try and login with them.

You cannot link more than one OAuth login to the same username, but one OAuth login can be linked to as many usernames as you like. If you want to use a different OAuth to the one you registered with you will need to go back to InfoQ's page and register again with a different username and your preferred social media account login.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, by account details I also wanted to check if the right contact detail, etc had been provided.

Comment: That's not accessible on the InfoQ webpage as you don't create an account on their side (so they can't be sure you own the personal information you're asking for). As long as the email address is correct then that's the important thing (again if you're unsure I'd register again to be safe).

Comment: This is funny, so we have a system with no feedback loop to the user. There isn't even an email / message sent to confirm to the user. Even on screen there is no confirmation at all. So what is the assurance that n'th registration worked correctly. Exactly how many times does one register to be sure?

Comment: I've taken this feedback on-board and will put this in our contest review. The difficult part here is the need to create and secure a way for people to login to an account on InfoQ's site to show if they are registered or not, which adds additional security considerations.

The basic feedback loop is if you enter the details and it lets you go to the next page it worked.